Search multiple cells for data "containing" a text string...then return the information from that cell
I am trying to figure out if there is a formula that will let me search multiple contiguous cells for a cell that contains a specific text string. If that value is found, I need the formula to display that text string.
Example: I have 27 cells in a row. Each cell contains a unique product SKU. I want to search all 27 cells and return the value of the cell that contains the text string "HD"
I tried: =MATCH("*-HD*",CI17:CM17,0), but that did not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I tried: =MATCH("*-HD*",CI17:CM17,0), but that did not work

=INDEX(C17:M17,,MATCH("*HD*",C17:M17,0))

=FILTER(C17:M17,IFERROR(SEARCH("hd",C17:M17),0)) to return multiple cells with "hd" text within

The MATCH(...) function returns the index of the found element in an array (representing the given range), meaning that it will only return one value if a match hits, or #N/A if not. Its search is always within the context of an array/cell-range.
The SEARCH(..) function, on the other hand, searches within the text of an element of an array, or cell. Therefore, the search is more like checking if a cell/array-element contains text or not. When you put an array/cell-range to it, the search process will be applied to every element/cell in the given array/cell-range, thus providing multiple results. meaning the keyword search is checked for every element, and a consequence result is returned for each. The result in this case will be the index of the first position in which the search keyword is found in the element/cell.
You can follow @user11222393 suggestion, though I personally prefer ISNUMBER() in this context as it takes one argument and the values are in text.
SOLUTION:
The short version of it:
= FILTER( CI17:CM17, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HD", CI17:CM17)) )

Or alternatively:
= FILTER( CI17:CM17, IFERROR(SEARCH("hd", CI17:CM17), 0) )

You can also write it as below for clarity:
= LET( source_row,       CI17:CM17,
       search_key,       "HD",
       search_result,    FILTER(source_row, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_key, source_row))),
       search_result
     )

The role of ISNUMBER() is to covert the array resulted from the SEARCH() to TRUE or FALSE. Similarly, the IFERROR(..., 0) assigns zeros for those that do not have a match. Then the FILTER is used to remove those matching FALSE or 0.
